# Read policy for aerospike java client

Tags: aerospike

I am working with com.aerospike:aerospike-client:4.0.6

When reading the records client.get() expects policy.
However I could not find exactly what to be passed here
Its working with null, but I cannot find REadPolicy (like its there for Write).
Is it ok to send null for policy, or is there better use of policy when reading the records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send null to use read Policy defaults. There are few read policy options that you can set. Usually defaults is all you need.

For reads, you create a Policy object and you can set timeout, maximum retries, sleep between retries, consistency level etc.  replica is also an interesting one replica.RANDOM can be used if deploying Aerospike in a look up table design - Read Java API docs help on "Policy" and see all the ones that apply to read operations. For replica settings, explore Replica further in the help.  http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/

```
eg:
// Java policy
Policy policy = new Policy();
policy.timeout = 50; // 50 milliseconds
```